# I need php/mysql to take 3 assignment marks (inserted by user), add them together and then divide by 3

Tags: php, mysql

I need php/mysql to take 3 assignment marks (inserted by user), add them together and then divide by 3 in order to get the average mark. This average mark then needs to be inserted into the grade column in the table.

Here is the code;

```
$a1 = $_REQUEST['ass1'];
$a2 = $_REQUEST['ass2'];
$a3 = $_REQUEST['ass3'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$t = '3';
$sum = "'$a1' + '$a2' + '$a3'";
$average = (int)($sum / $t);

mysql_select_db("kackieco_final",$con);
$q = "UPDATE grades SET ass1=$a1, ass2=$a2, ass3=$a3, grade=$average WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: so what basically is the error you face?

Comment: what is the problem with the code???

Comment: Why don't you give me a link to this project you're working on. I'd be more then happy to teach you a nice good lesson about SQL injection, the hard way. xD

Comment: Please tell us what this code does when you run it, and how it differs from what you want. This makes it a lot easier for readers to help you without having to do a complete code review and make random guesses about your website / environment / use case.

Comment: Sorry, with the code shown above I want it to insert '$average' into the grades column. However it doesn't insert anything into the grades column as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Your $sum is a string containing the 3 numbers and mathematical operators.

Literally

```
'1' + '2' + '3'
// string(15) "'1' + '2' + '3'"
```

http://codepad.org/Nxcdrkyk

Get rid of the quotes

```
$sum = $a1 + $a2 + $a3;
// int(6)
```

http://codepad.org/RWvTSfv8

And you'll get your int

Comment: I'm good bro. Be sure to mark as your answer if this worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, in your code you're treating the values as strings:

```
<?php
//Example values, simulate a request
$_REQUEST['id']='25';
$_REQUEST['ass1']='17';
$_REQUEST['ass2']='28';
$_REQUEST['ass3']='32';


//Get and check the values from the user
$values=array();
$values['id'] = (isset($_REQUEST['id']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['id']))?$_REQUEST['id']:0;
$values[1] = (isset($_REQUEST['ass1']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ass1']))?$_REQUEST['ass1']:0;
$values[2] = (isset($_REQUEST['ass2']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ass2']))?$_REQUEST['ass2']:0;
$values[3] = (isset($_REQUEST['ass3']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ass3']))?$_REQUEST['ass3']:0;
$values['t'] = 3;

//one line add the variables together then devide by 3 and then round down or up depending on whats closest
$values['average'] = round(( ($values[1] + $values[2] + $values[3]) / $values['t'])); //26


$q = "UPDATE grades SET ass1={$values[1]}, ass2={$values[2]}, ass3={$values[3]}, grade={$values['average']} WHERE id = {$values['id']}";

echo $q;
//UPDATE grades SET ass1=17, ass2=28, ass3=32, grade=26 WHERE id = 25
?>
```